# Hide spinner after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide spinner after loading the page 
I tried with this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.loader')
    .hide()  // Hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

 });
```

And I have this div :

```
<style>
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url("{{ asset('img/loading.gif') }}" )  50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);

}
</style>
    <div class="loader"></div>
```

But no result.

Comment: Hi Martin. Can you explain the ajaxStart and ajaxStop functions please? Is this code related to a specific library or plugin or are you intending to write those?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9, all the handlers for the jQuery global Ajax events, including those added with the `.ajaxStart()` method, must be attached to `document` - [**Docs**](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

Answer (score 1):

> You can achive this by Using `.ajaxSend()` and `.ajaxComplete()` [Ajax Event 
>   Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

1. **.ajaxSend()** : Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery triggers the `ajaxSend` event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxSend()` method are executed at this time.
2. **.ajaxComplete()** : Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery triggers the `ajaxComplete` event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxComplete()` method are executed at this time.

I used the below code to show a loader when ajax request is made and then hide it after ajax request complete.

Here is the code:

```
var ajax_req_no = 0;
(function ($) {
$(document).ajaxSend(function () {
        ajax_req_no = (ajax_req_no < 0) ? 0 : ajax_req_no;
        ajax_req_no++;
        if ($('.loader').length) {
            $('.loader').show();
        }
    });

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        ajax_req_no--;
        ajax_req_no = (ajax_req_no < 0) ? 0 : ajax_req_no;
        if ($('.loader').length && ajax_req_no == 0) {
            $('.loader').fadeOut();
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

As there can be a nesting of ajax request so `ajax_req_no` is to count the number of request if the count is more then one loder will be shown otherwise loder will be hidden.

**Note:** As of jQuery version 1.8, this method should only be attached to `document`.

---

Reference:

- [.ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/)
- [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to just put a `.show()` in the code preceding the ajax call and then a `.hide()` in the `.success()` or `.done()` along the lines of...

```
$("#buttonStartingAjax").click(function(){
    $(".loader").show();
    $.ajax({...}).done(function(){
        $(".loader").hide();
        ...
    });
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you're looking for something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document)
    .ajaxStart(function() {
      console.log('some AJAX request has started'); 
      $(".loader").show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
      console.log('all AJAX requests have completed'); 
      $(".loader").hide();
    })
  ;

  $("#btn").click(function() {
    // trigger some AJAX call
    $.get('example.com');
  });
});
```

```css
.loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*z-index: 9999;*/ /* to see demo's console.log */
  background: url("img/loading.gif")  50% 50% no-repeat yellow;
  display: none; /* unless overriden by jQuery */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="loader"></div>

<button id="btn">Trigger an AJAX request</button>
```