# Stop Ladda button spin after successfully submit ajax form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code for submitting form data to post_receiver.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery post form data using .post() method by codeofaninja.com</title>

    </head>
<body>

<h1>jQuery post form data using .post() method</h1>
<div>Fill out and submit the form below to get response.</div>

<!-- our form -->  
<form id='userForm'>
    <div><input type='text' name='firstname' placeholder='Firstname' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='lastname' placeholder='Lastname' /></div>
    <div><input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' /></div>
    <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
</form>

<!-- where the response will be displayed -->
<div id='response'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#userForm').submit(function(){

        // show that something is loading
        $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

        /*
         * 'post_receiver.php' - where you will pass the form data
         * $(this).serialize() - to easily read form data
         * function(data){... - data contains the response from post_receiver.php
         */
        $.post('post_receiver.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){

            // show the response
            $('#response').html(data);

        }).fail(function() {

            // just in case posting your form failed
            alert( "Posting failed." );

        });

        // to prevent refreshing the whole page page
        return false;

    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

There is no problem with this code. But I am using Ladda button to show spin effect for submit button (this one: https://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/), and I want this effect will stop immediately after results return.

I searched and found some answers for similar question on this website, but as a newbie that almost understand nothing about Javascript and Ajax, I still couldn't resolve my problem.

So someone please tell me what the code I need to insert more. Appreciate all your helps!

Comment: Add a `.always()` to the end of your `$.post` and stop the spinning with `stop()`. The page you linked has the example code at the bottom.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40513161/5019802

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add `l.stop()` after `$('#response').html(data);`, but it depends how you've initialized Ladda.

If it doesn't work, post that code too.

Comment: It was very lately but I still need to say thank you. Solution Accepted!